# How to install and open the Android studio in windows 7 (64 bit)?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have downloaded the android studio bundle from android website. I have set environmental variable for JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME. Now I am able to open the android studio. But while opening, the process "Fetching Android SDK component information" is loading still. I am waiting for half an hour. But the loading is not closed. I am under proxy network. What should i have to do for opening android studio ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android SDK already installed - try to point ANDROID_HOME Environmental variable to folder with SDK.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have set the ANDROD_HOME environmental variable. But the loading still persist.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Enter the bin folder of Android Studio and open idea.properties.
```

2. Add one line in the end of idea.properties: disable.android.first.run=true, save it.

3. Close android studio and reopen it.